# Laravel, foreach e banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Eu tenho a seguinte tabela no banco de dados

```
  public function up()
{
     Schema::create('cidades', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('uf');
        $table->string('nome_uf');
        $table->integer('mesorregiao_geografica');
        $table->string('nome_nesorregiao');
        $table->integer('microrregiao_geografica');
        $table->string('nome_microrregiao');
        $table->integer('municipio');
        $table->integer('cod_municipio_completo');
        $table->string('nome_municipio');
    });
}
```

Já criei o model cidade

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Cidade extends Model
{
    //
}
```

já testei inserir dados a partir do tinker e funcionou.

```
use App\Cidade
$cidade= new cidade
$cidade->nome_uf= "teste";
$franqueado->save();
```

Porém agora eu não consigo dar um foreach, no view.... Como eu faço para listar o nome de todas cidades e dar um foreach para aparecer no view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro aconselho a você a inserir no seu Model os valores que serão editáveis com o parâmetro fillable.

**Model (na pasta do seu projeto \app\Cidade.php)**

```
<?php namespace Cidades;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Cidade extends Model {

    //------------Dados Editavéis----------------------
    //Definindo dados que poderão ser alterados
    protected $fillable = [
        'uf',
        'nome_uf',
        'mesorregiao_geografica',
        'nome_nesorregiao',
        'microrregiao_geografica',
        'nome_microrregiao',
        'municipio',
        'cod_municipio_completo',
        'nome_municipio'
    ];

}
```

**Controller CidadeController.php**

```
...
public function index()
{
    $cidades = \Cidades\Cidade::orderBy('id');
    return view('cidade.index', compact('cidades'));
}
...
```

**View index.blade.php no seu projeto na pasta \resources\views**

```
...
<tr>
    <th> ID </th>
    <th> UF </th>
    <th> NOME UF </th>
    <th> ... </th>
</tr>
@if($cidades)
    @foreach($cidades as $cidade)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$cidade->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$cidade->uf}}</td>
            <td>{{$cidade->nome_uf}}</td>
            <td>{{$cidade->...}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@endif
...
```

Não tem erro

Comment: Na realidade se vais colocar todos os campos como `$fillable` mais vale usares `protected $guarded = [];`, https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#mass-assignment

Answer (score 1):

Levando em consideração que o seu `ORM` está funcionando, vou te mostrar uma forma simples de resolver o problema, o compartilhamento de dados entre um método do `controller` e sua `view` funciona da seguinte maneira:

app\Http\Controllers\UserController.php

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $users = User::all();

        return view('user.index', compact('users'));
    }
}
```

Como estou buscando a view `'user.index'` no controller, vamos precisar do arquivo no exato local:

resources/views/user/index.blade.php

```
...

<ul>
@foreach ($users as $user)
    <li>
        {{ $user->name }}
    </li>
@endforeach
</ul>

..
```

Se você está com dificuldades neste assunto, sugiro uma leitura completa dos tópicos relacionados a ORM na [documentação oficial do Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#retrieving-multiple-models), está em ingles mas é um texto simples e de fácil leitura.

Comment: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\User' not found

Deu este erro

Comment: Você não deve utilizar a classe User, e sim a classe Cidade.  Eu utilizei User só para você entender o processo de compartilhar informações entre o controller e a view. É muito importante você acompanhar um tutorial antes de tentar fazer seus próprios projetos, como [este](https://laravel.com/docs/master/quickstart) por exemplo, da documentação oficial do Laravel.