# laravel foreach view

Tags: php, array, laravel

Tenho esse array e ele pode ser infinito, com diversos filhos
https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=cff2cb9795a64273142b24b83e73ffe3 como eu faço um foreach nisso em uma view?

Comment: Um array infinito? Imagina o quanto de processamento não vai precisar.

Comment: já tenho isso velho, digo infinito, pq de fato nunca vou saber qnd ele acaba, ele pode acabar um ou niveis, ou com até x niveis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um exemplo de como iterar um array, suponha que você tem o seguinte `array`:

```
array (size=3)
  'clients' => 
    array (size=4)
      'Super Fish' => 
        array (size=2)
          'totalminutes' => int 49
          'totalcost' => float 28.58774
      'Swedish Fish' => 
        array (size=2)
          'totalminutes' => int 16
          'totalcost' => float 5.85842
      'Aero Fish' => 
        array (size=2)
          'totalminutes' => int 7
          'totalcost' => float 0.29714
      'Happy Fish' => 
        array (size=2)
          'totalminutes' => int 44
          'totalcost' => float 18.16224
  'totalminutes' => int 116
  'totalcost' => float 52.90554
```

**seu controller ficaria como este codigo:**

```
$data = Reports\InternationalCallsReport::create();
return View::make('reports.international-calls')->with('data', $data);
```

**o código na view apenas com foreach:**

```
foreach($data['clients'] as $k => $v) {
    echo $k . '<br>';
    foreach ($v as $key => $value) {
        echo $key . ' => ' . $value . '<br>';
    }
}
```

**Na versão blade:**

```
@foreach($data['clients'] as $k => $v)
    {{ $k }} 
    @foreach ($v as $key => $value) 
        {{ $key . ' => ' . $value }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Não importa se ele seja finito ou infinito, o `[FOREACH][1]` irá percorrer todos os elementos até que o array acabe.

**Mas isso é bom?**

Depende do que você está tentando fazer, de qualquer forma existem várias maneiras de para um laço infinito. Como por exemplo:

> você pode criar uma condição com o `if` .. se o tempo demorar mais de
>   3 minutos e ai utilizar o código `[break][1]`, o break finaliza a
>   execução da estrutura for, foreach, while, do-while ou switch atual.

alguns links de referencia que podem de ajudar:

[Laravel Foreach com Banco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/136096/laravel-foreach-e-banco-de-dados?rq=1) 
[Pass Array to Blade](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/passing-arrays-to-blade-and-iterating)

Comment: eu sei que a pergunta não está muito clara, porem se minha resposta de ajudou, estude votar nela como útil.